# Silverlight Unit tests can't be run (using ReSharper or NUnit): dependency error appears

Tags: silverlight, unit-testing, typemock

CThru.Silverlight can't find dependent libraries Typemock.Isolator.VisualBasic & Typemock.ArrangeActAssert of Version=6.0.2.0
but there are versions 6.0.3.0  of these libraries registered.

Any workaround?
Where to download Typemock 6.0.2.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right - the version of Isolator on the website contains the wrong references. We'll take care of that!

In the mean time, please download this version - it contains CThru with fixed references: http://www.typemock.com/patches/TypemockIsolatorSetup6.0.3.619.msi

Thanks!